# excel paste special function in vba not pasting cell widths

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I'm running a macro to copy from one sheet and past to another however, it is not pasting the cell width.  If I do this manually it works i.e. copy the column and paste special > all.  the vba code for the macro is located here: http://pastebin.com/K2sW1C8x

as you can see i'm using :

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paste of the column widths need to be done in a separate action:

```
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlColumnWidths
```

This command occasionally threw an error in previous versions of Excel. If you get an error, use the number 8 in place of xlColumnwidths.

Comment: Does this mean I'll have to have two lines for paste special i.e.
one that does xlPasteAll and then a line following that with xlColumnWidths

Comment: Yes, the same as when you do a paste of column widths by hand.

Comment: I never pasted the column widths by hand, when I would manually do the paste all it would automatically put the correct width but when I ran it through the macro it wouldn't paste the widths in.  That was the issure I was having trouble with.

Comment: Exactly the info I was missing. Even though you need to correct `xlColumnWidths` to `xlPasteColumnWidths`.

Comment: I still get `Run-time error '1004'  - Application-defined or object-defined error` if I use 8. This is the above line after doing a `ActiveSheet.Paste`